# Twilio Listening In - Creating conference by modifying live call

Tags: twilio

I'm trying to create a "Listen In" feature, where an admin can pick an call in-progress and listen in muted.

I figured out that I need to create a conference and join the admin as muted but it doesn't seem to work.

I'm creating a dial TWIML with a conference node, when the call is made. But what that does is just add the caller to a conference but never call the client.

Also, when the admin wants to join the conference, does he need to have a number to call in from, or would the callSid suffice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like if the call was made using  Twiml, redirecting that call using REST API (redirect method) will drop either the parent or the child leg, depending on the Sid passed. Using the REST API to initiate outbound calls works better.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into the RestAPI for changing call state, it looks like you can redirect calls based on the callSid.

https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/change-call-state

Comment: It should and I've been trying that but for some reason it drops my calls before it hits the web hooks to retrieve the TwiML. Thanks!

Comment: Looks like if the call was made using <Dial> Twiml, redirecting that call will drop either the parent or the child leg, depending on the Sid passed. Using the REST API to initiate outbound calls works better.